# Conditional Class Toggling

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I asked another question recently regarding toggling classes. Initially I thought there was a solution, but it looks like I'm still having some problems. I am trying to build a small site that shows failures and successes for some items. Here is an example of what I'm trying to build: http://jsfiddle.net/zrYLh/4/

**How the site should work:** 
If I check the box for Computer A, Computers A, B, C & D should go red. If I then check the box for Computer B, nothing should change. If I then uncheck the box for Computer B, all items should still remain red, because Computer A is still checked and it should result in red for A,B,C and D on it's own. The same logic should hold for any combination of checks.

---

Currently the code forces certain items to toggle back to green even if another item requires that they stay red. For example, when A and B are checked, and then B is unchecked, it forces A and C to go green.

Here's my script as of now:

```
$('#computerA').click(function(){
    var state = this.checked;
    $('#computerA2, #computerB2, #computerC2, #computerD2').toggleClass('green', !state).toggleClass('failure', state);
})

$('#computerB, #computerC, #computerD').click(function(){
    var state = this.checked || $('#computerA').is(':checked');
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('green', !state).toggleClass('failure', state);
})

$('#computerB').click(function(){
    var state = this.checked;
    $('#computerA2, #computerC2').toggleClass('green', !state).toggleClass('failure', state);
})

$('#computerA, #computerC').click(function(){
    var state = this.checked || $('#computerB').is(':checked');
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('green', !state).toggleClass('failure', state);
})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are after, but if I understand you correct, there is actually a css-only solution to this.

Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/zrYLh/5/

What did I do:

- I restructured your html a bit. Not all necessary, but more semantically correct imo, and a lot easier to maintain by removing a lot of the id's. It is however necessary to place the label before the checkbox for this technique to work.
- The restructuring meant I had do change some of your css to make it work again. Again a bit easier to maintain now, and got rid of most of the absolute positioning (only use them if it is the only possible way, or you'll regret it when you ever have to change something in your code)

The 'magic' lies in the following line of css:

```
#business input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label {
    background-color: red;
}
```

This selector allows you to select all labels that are preceded by a checked checkbox.

For more info you could read this about the `:checked` pseudo class:
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/
Or this about the sibling selector `~`:
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/g/general-sibling/

Answer (score 0):

Try this update of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/JB3kM/1/.

Please note that you did not specify what should happen if you do the following:

1. Check A
2. Check B
3. Uncheck A

Should then be B green or still A? If B, remove the part `this.checked &&` from line 3...